# How to archive iOS build with xcodebuild?

Tags: iphone, ios, build-automation, xcodebuild

I'm attempting to create a script that builds and archives my iOS project. My goal is to have a script that creates AdHoc and Distribution ipas.

I've attempted something like this:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyApp -configuration AdHoc archive
```

It works when I execute this command in the terminal. But when I put it in a shell script file and then run it from the terminal:

```
sudo sh /Users/user/somepath/buildscript.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
Provisioning profile 'XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX' can't be found
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sudo` invocation of the script cannot find what it needs because the certificates and provisioning profiles required will be stored in your account's keychain and Xcode library directories. `sudo` will be running as the administrator which can't see these.

You should't need to use `sudo` anyway. What part of your build process requires root privileges? If you want to somehow isolate this command, create a new user specifically for building, but install the appropriate certificate in the user's keychain, and drag the provisioning profile into Xcode while logged in as that user.

Comment: I merely want to run the script file in the terminal. When executing /Users/user/somepath/buildscript.sh in the terminal in gives me "Permission denied". This is why I use sudo

Comment: You need to enable execution with chmod for it to work: `chmod u+x /path/to/script.sh`